# C#: How do I create an instance with a generic while it has been declared as object

Tags: c#, generics

I am facing a problem where I want to create an instance of a `SomeClass<T>` where `T` is giving by the method, but `SomeClass<T>` is added to a dictionary that is declared like `ConcurrentDictionary<OtherClass, SomeClass<object>>`. What I want to do does not compile because `Type 'T' doesn't match expected type object`

```cs
private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim;
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<StatisticType, StatisticsList<object>> statisticsDictionary;

public StatisticsDictionary()
{
    semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
    statisticsDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<StatisticType, StatisticsList<object>>();
}

(...)

public bool TryAdd<T>(StatisticType key, DateTime dateTime, T value)
{
    if (!statisticsDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        semaphoreSlim.Wait();
        statisticsDictionary.TryAdd(key, new StatisticsList<T>());
        semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }

    if (!statisticsDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var statistics))
        return false;

    statistics.Add(dateTime, value);
    return true;
}
```

The concurrentDictionary is wrapped in a class that needs to support different types of 'T' (like long, DateTime, TimeSpan and possibly other types)

I've tried to just initialize `SomeClass<T>` as `SomeClass<object>` so that it matches the declaration. And then on retrieval cast `object` to `T` that is given by the method. But this leads to casting exceptions because it seems to be impossible to (explicitly) cast an object to, for example, long even when the object is in fact a long during run time.

```cs
public bool TryGetFrom<T>(StatisticType key, DateTime from, out IEnumerable<(DateTime, T)> value)
{
    if (statisticsDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var statistics))
    {
        var list = statistics.TryGetFrom(from);
        value = (IEnumerable<(DateTime, T)>) list;

        return value != null;
    }

    value = null;
    return false;
}
```

Is it even possible what I try to accomplish?

---

**Edit** Source code of StatisticsList as requested in the comments

```
public class StatisticsList<T>
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim;
    private readonly SortedList<DateTime, (DateTime, T)> sortedList;
    public DateTime StartedAt { get; }
    public int Count => sortedList.Count;

    public StatisticsList()
    {
        try
        {
            semaphoreSlim.Wait();
            sortedList.Add(key, (key, value));
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphoreSlim.Release();
        }
    }

    public void Add(DateTime key, T value)
    {
        semaphoreSlim.Wait();
        sortedList.Add(key, (key, value));
        semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }

    public bool TryGetFrom(DateTime from, out IEnumerable<(DateTime, T)> value)
    {
        try
        {
            semaphoreSlim.Wait();
            value = sortedList.Where(s => s.Key > from).Select(s => s.Value).ToList();
            return true;
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException) { }
        finally
        {
            semaphoreSlim.Release();
        }

        value = null;
        return false;
    }

    public bool TryGetLast(out (DateTime, T) value)
    {
        try
        {
            semaphoreSlim.Wait();
            var dateTime = sortedList.Max(s => s.Key);
            return sortedList.TryGetValue(dateTime, out value);
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            value = (default, default);
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphoreSlim.Release();
        }

        return false;
    }

    public IEnumerable<(DateTime, T)> ToList()
    {
        try
        {
            semaphoreSlim.Wait();
            return sortedList.Values.ToList();
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphoreSlim.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you declare the dictionary as `ConcurrentDictionary<StatisticType, StatisticsList<T>>`? Do you want to support different types of objects in the same dictionary?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I need to support different types of objects in the same dictionary indeed. And I do not know all the type because this may change in the future

Comment: @Yokovaski `GetOrAdd` does that for you, automatically (well, it may create multiple of them - but only one will be added to the `ConcurrentDictionary` so it will do what your code does in a much simpler way). You don't need the semaphore.

Comment: Just because two types, `A` and `B` have a particular inheritance relationship, that does *not* mean, in general, that a generic parameterized by those types exhibit the same inheritance relationship. In general (ignoring covariance, etc), `G<A>` and `G<B>` will have *no* inheritance relationship.

Comment: The use of generics in you context is inappropriate, you can just aswell use an object for all of your methods. Go do that there is no good reason not to either use an object or implement an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics are effective when you know the type during design-time. In your case, your collection can store items of any different types.

You can utilize a pretty popular trick of declaring non-generic and inherited generic version of a collection item. 
As a side effect, you can get rid of a not-very-readable value tuple :)

Declare item class like this:

```
public abstract class StatisticsListItem
{
    public DateTime Time { get; protected set; }
}

public class StatisticsListItem<T> : StatisticsListItem 
{
    public StatisticsListItem(DateTime time, T value)
    {
        Time = time;
        Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; }
}
```

And then you can store them as `StatisticsListItem` and perform operations depending on their specific sub-type. It is also type-safe, because you cannot access the value of a generic list item, like in case if you declare it as non-generic `StatisticsListItem` with `object Value { get; }` property.

The simplest usage scenario can look like this:

```
public class StatisticsList
{
    public List<StatisticsListItem> Values { get; set; } = new List<StatisticsListItem>();

    public void TryAdd<T>(DateTime dateTime, T value)
    {
        // Adding an item of generic type to non-generic list:
        Values.Add(new StatisticsListItem<T>(dateTime, value));
    }

    public IEnumerable<StatisticsListItem<T>> TryGetFrom<T>(DateTime dateTime) 
    {  
        // Dynamically filtering only items of specific generic type
        return Values
            .OfType<StatisticsListItem<T>>() // computationally ineffective, subject to improvement ;)
            .Where(t => t.Time >= dateTime); // same, just an example
    }
}
```

It is just an example. You still need to implement it in a way it supports keys, fits into your dictionary and makes filtering of items by type much more effective. Good luck!

Some minor comments: you still might have some problems with handling multi-threading, but this is out of the scope of this question :)

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for the comment, English is not my first language indeed, I've tried to make it better now :) I've tried to focus primarily on generic\non-generic question and let the OP deal with multithreading / dictionary code on their own, because it is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: I will try to work this suggestion into my code. I like the solution thus far!

Comment: Took a few hours before I could pick this up, but I worked this solution in my code and it works like a charm!